# Upside down glance screen

Tags: 8.1-update-1, developer-preview, glance

Found that, sometimes my glance screen getting displayed upside down, interestingly sometimes mirrored view of the same and blinking of glance screen some other times. I'm using glance screen background. But seems that it's not the culprit. Read the similar issues at windowscentral.com. But, I'm not using remote desktop app.

I'm on **Lumia 620** with **Windows Phone 8.1 Update Developer Preview** ***8.10.14219.341***, firmware of ***3058.50000.1425.0001*** and **Glance Background** ***1.0.1.1***

Comment: It happened with me once. Some app with ability to change my lock screen was the responsible. I found the blamed app through try and error, uninstalling every lock screen app that I've had in my phone until find the one that was causing the problem.

Comment: @FabioSilva, I'm having Weather app. I'm not using it as lock screen app. My lock screen is the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by an other app, possibly the Microsoft Remote Desktop or Movie Moments app. Try opening and flipping the app to it's default orientation.

> If you rotate Remote Desktop to be landscaped/flipped to the right side, your Glance screen will go back to normal without the need for a soft reset.

A soft reset should do the trick as well!

Source: [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/glance-screen-flipping-upside-down-users-heres-why)